# JavaScript: Replace part of the text is stored in a string variable that starts with '$"?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm aware that replacing can be done on other most easier ways, but because of the complexity of my code, I have to do it on the way I started below.

What I need is to replace `$WORD.A` and `$WORD.B` with `TEST` and something goes wrong at the line.

```
newValue.replace(new RegExp(potentialWord, 'g'), 'TEST');
```

In the code below, my problem is when I want to replace a string variable that starts with the character `$` with another variable.

```js
const paragraph = 'My text for replace this $WORD.A and this $WORD.B';
let newValue = paragraph;
console.log("OLD text: ", paragraph);
const regex = /(?:\$)([A-Z]+(?:\.[A-Z])*)/gm;
const foundPossibleWords = newValue.match(regex);
console.log(foundPossibleWords);
if (foundPossibleWords != null && foundPossibleWords !== undefined) {
  foundPossibleWords.forEach((potentialWord) => {
    newValue.replace(new RegExp(potentialWord, 'g'), 'TEST');
  });
}
console.log("NEW text: ", newValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this matches your needs ?

```js
const paragraph = 'My text for replace this $WORD.A and this $WORD.B and $ANOTHER_WORD';
const re = /\$[^\s]+/gm;
const replacement = 'TEST';

var result = paragraph.replace(re, replacement);

console.log("NEW text: ", result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```js
const paragraph = 'My text for replace this $WORD.A and this $WORD.B';
const res = paragraph.replace(/[\$][\w\.]+/g, 'TEST');
console.log(res);
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/mMT9Lc/1)